# How to change the monero-wallet-gui rendering mode for older computers

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

On old machines (with integrated graphics), displaying the GUI might not work. it will either crash on startup or display a white/black window.

How can the user change the rendering mode and what is its effect?

Answer (score 13):

Here is how to do it:

**Linux & OS-X:**

The easiest way is probably to launch it via terminal (has to happen in the same terminal session).

```
QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui
```

**Windows:**

1. Click the Start button, right-click the Computer option in the Start menu, and select Properties.
2. Click the Advanced System Settings link in the left column.
3. In the System Properties window, click on the Advanced tab, then click the Environment Variables button near the bottom of that tab.
4. In the Environment Variables window you can now add a new User Environment Variable. Name=QMLSCENE_DEVICE / Value=softwarecontext

Allright, so far so good. but what does it really do ?

The different isnt that easy to spot, but for users on old machines it will make a big difference :-)
you might notice the difference when comparing the font.

[image: Here on the left side you can see it running with the Quick 2D Rendering Option enabled]

Comment: Depends on your shell, but with typical bash, monero-core will not inherit the value of that variable. You want either s/set/export/ or QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-core

Comment: It doesn't work anyway for me, I am on Windows Server 2012 R2.
This file doesn't seem to exist in this installation.
Should I install Visual C++ in example?