# Getting Monero GUI running on ubuntu

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

When attempting to run the start-gui.sh in terminal I am receiving:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platforms plugin "xcb". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I have already attempted to install the library dependencies via:

```
apt-get install qt5-default
```

However I am still receiving the plugin dependency error.

Any help with resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I'm a new monero user here ( I was waiting for the gui) , I've managed to run successfully Monero GUI on Ubuntu 16.04.1 and Lubuntu 16.04.1 from a full installation on an usb stick on a very old laptop (and using an external daemon), hence why I switched to lubuntu which runs much better.

I encountered the problem you describe I did the following to solve it:

> sudo apt-get install qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
>
> sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtquick-controls
>   qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel
>
> sudo apt-get install qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects

If you want to speed up even more [I tried the following on lubuntu after ditching ubuntu](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/how-to-change-the-monero-wallet-gui-rendering-mode-for-older-computers/2929#2929)

You'll need

> sudo apt-get install libunbound2

and then do:

> set QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-core
>
> set QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui

and then start

> ./start-gui.sh

If the above command will not start the GUI try

> QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui

Be aware that I think there is a bug when you create a wallet from a seed it just sometimes does not led pass to the next screen, the right arrow control is not activated but if you start typing on the name of the wallet, the right arrow control activates and then you can click to the next screen with the  wallet recreated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The steps outlined above for the most part helped me, however I was unable to start the GUI by entering 
"./start-gui.sh"
but but had success in starting it with
"QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext ./monero-wallet-gui"
from the start-gui.sh directory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is a temporary solution. we are currently working so the Beta runs "out of the box" on those systems.

once the next release is out this issue should be solved.