# Fail to execute Monero GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Monero GUI gives me error system when trying to launch.
"api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll missing on your computer"
Now when looking for solutions online I found this on the official Microsoft board :

> Those DLLs are Windows's implementation detail and are subject to
>   change at anytime. Any software that report those are missing are
>   reporting wrong information (e.g. reporting a delay-loaded dependency
>   as hard one). Your Windows machine most likely cannot boot if those
>   are expected to be present in the Windows version but missing.
>
> Don't try to obtain them. Distributing those files is against Windows
>   end user agreement. Just use the APIs documented in the Windows SDK
>   (unless absolute necessary like writing antivirus). Those APIs may or
>   may not use the DLLs you listed, but their dependencies are not yours
>   to worry.

I'm confused. What does that mean ? Thanks.

Comment: Try this http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/how-to-change-the-monero-wallet-gui-rendering-mode-for-older-computers