# How to fix blank gui wallet splash screen?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have downloaded the Windows x64 wallet but when I run the monero-wallet-gui.exe, the splash screen is a blank white borderless windows and stops there.

I downloaded a couple times with same result, which doesn't even register on the Task manager as a functioning application.

Is this normal?

Monerod seems to work, it's syncing the blockchain to \bitmonero.

(Acer laptop, W7 x64: The Linux Gui wallet works fine on the Ubuntu partition.)

Comment: Can you try this method? http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/how-to-change-the-monero-wallet-gui-rendering-mode-for-older-computers