# Monero GUI Crash on Launch "api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll is missing"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

When I copy over/unzip/run a fresh copy of v0.13.0.4 GUI on my spare laptop, the program fails to open and says "api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-2-0.dll" is missing. The window keeps popping back up after hitting OK and the Monero GUI fails to load.

[image: Monero GUI Crash Message]

This computer is running Windows 7 with all latest updates, but I'm assuming it's missing a library from Microsoft somewhere. Google searching talks about Win 10 upgrades, but I've never done that. I've ran the same zip file on several other computers with no issue.

I've already tried installing x64 C++ redistributable packages which finish in successful installation but the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have an AV (AntiVirus) running that might be quarantining files required for the GUI to run properly?

Answer (score 1):

Following links contains solution:

(1) [api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-2-0.dll is Missing](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-gui/issues/340)

(2) [change-the-monero-wallet-gui-rendering-mode](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/how-to-change-the-monero-wallet-gui-rendering-mode-for-older-computers/2929#2929)

**Linux & OS-X:**

QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext

**.**/monero-wallet-gui

**Windows:**

Add User Environment Variable.

Name=QMLSCENE_DEVICE

Value=softwarecontext

Now run monero-wallet-gui, this time there should be no error. Hope this helps.